# Selecting one or more rows in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable made from scanning a csv file and it just stores the info right into the datatable. I then want to be able to use my mouse to select one or more rows in that DT, however I don't know how to do this. Here is the code that makes the table:

```
        dt.Columns.Add("Mouse Command")
        dt.Columns.Add("Mouse Position")

        Dim delimiter As String = ","
        Using parser As New TextFieldParser(file)
            parser.SetDelimiters(delimiter)
            parser.ReadLine()
            parser.ReadLine()
            parser.ReadFields()
            While Not parser.EndOfData
                ' Read in the fields for the current line
                fields = parser.ReadFields()
                r = dt.NewRow
                r("Mouse Command") = fields(0)
                r("Mouse Position") = fields(2)
                dt.Rows.Add(r)
            End While
```

Answer (score 0):

A datatable isn't a user interface construct, it's used for storing data.  You'll need to bind your data table to some kind of UI construct, like a GridView -- and then worry about your mouse clicks.

Comment: DataGridView for WinForms. Just set the .DataSource to the Datatable